# Best practice for Socket.IO Login with Cookies

Tags: cookies, authentication, socket.io

I'm looking for best practices for a Socket.IO based Login with Cookies. So far, the Login exists but now I'd like to write a cookie without sending a new page and when the user comes back he will still be logged in. Am I right when I say that it's impossible with Socket.IO since at least the Flash-Fallback won't save the coookie correctly on client-side?

Comment: This is completely possible.  Usually you use http to manipulate cookies, and have socket.io read them. Are you using express.js to serve the pages?  If so I can give you an example of how to share cookies between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Sails](http://sailsjs.com)** solves this problem by mocking Express requests for each incoming Socket.io call.  One case you'll want to consider is if a ws:// request hits *before* an http:// request ever goes through.  In that case, you won't have a cookie yet.  Rather than completely abandoning cookies as a persistence system, what I usually do, in the absence of a cookie, is trigger an http request to try and acquire one.  Hope that helps!